# One by one making a histogram out each column of a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table that looks like this. (In reality, there are over a million rows and 70-something columns)

```
ind1 ind2 ind3 ... indn
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5
1.0 0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9
```

I want an automated procedure to create a histogram for every column in the table. This is the code I have, but it doesn't work

```
for (i in 1:10){
  plN <- ggplot(cdf, aes(x=colnames(cdf)[i])) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)
  plot(plN)
}
```

How do I extract the column name for the ith column of the dataframe, so I can plug that in in place of x=...? The current setup doesn't work.

(Answered in Duck's comment below. Thanks for the help!)

Comment: `aes(x=cdf[,i])`

Comment: @dnv89 If answers are useful and helpful, please upvote them, as that helps helps the community.

Comment: @akaDrHouse, sorry about that. Duck's comment above worked for me, and I just went with that. It didn't let me upvote it, since it is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

We can store the output in a `list`

```
plN <- vector('list', ncol(cdf))
for(i in seq_along(cdf)) {
      plN[[i]] <- ggplot(cdf, aes(x= !! rlang::sym(names(cdf)[i]) + 
                 geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)

 }

plN[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also like writing single functions and then using a loop to call the function.

I'll create your dataset with some random numbers.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
cdf <- data.frame(
  A = rnorm(1000, -3, 1),
  B = rnorm(1000, 1, 1),
  C = rnorm(1000, 5, 10),
  D = rnorm(1000, -3, 2)
)
```

Then write a function to graph a given dataset and function.  I also include whether to print it.

```
myhist_function <- function(mydata, mycolumn, printit = F) {
  mycolname <- colnames(mydata)[mycolumn]
  coltograph <- mydata[mycolumn]
  ggplot(mydata, aes(x = mydata[, mycolumn])) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) +
    xlab(mycolname) -> plN
    if (printit == T) {
      print(plN)
    }
  return(plN)
}
```

Calling the function as such once looks like:

```
myhist_function(mydata = cdf, mycolumn = 2, printit = T)
```

[image: functioncal]

Then I can create an empty list, and loop over whatever columns I desire for any given dataset. And populate the list with `ggplot2` graph objects.

```
mygraphs <- list()

columns_toplot <- names(cdf)
for (i in seq_along(columns_toplot)) {
  mygraphs[[i]] <-
    myhist_function(mydata = cdf, mycolumn = i, printit = F)
}
names(mygraphs) <- columns_toplot
```

You can visualize any graph you wish by `mygraphs[[i]]`, but you can also use the `ggarrange()` function from the ggpubr package to do things like this:

```
library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(mygraphs[[1]],
          mygraphs[[2]],
          mygraphs[[3]],
          mygraphs[[4]],
          ncol = 2,
          nrow = 2)
```

[image: ggarrange example]